# passing and comparing datetime values with different timezones in elastic search and nest

Tags: c#, datetime, elasticsearch, timezone, nest

I am trying to pass a datetime value as an argument (timezone incognizant value which is in timezone 'UTC') in a query that compares the argument to a datetime value (timezone congnizant value which is in timezone '-05:00') inside an elastic search doc and returns documents.

Questions:

1. Am I doing it correctly in my code below? 

    2. Is ES going to handle the complexity of different timezone of the datetime argument before comparing it to the document datetime values ?

    3. Is ES going to return the documents with the original datetime timezone values ?

    4. Any documentation unraveling the internals of elastic search instance timezone handling ?


The below code returns values, but I am unsure if it is achieving the desired objective.

Followed this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) but it is limited to some basics

    Thanks in advance.

ES source document:

```
{
  "took" : 12,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },

  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2700881,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test_index",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "R22224!!5333e7e4-9ee3-45f4-9dc3-2a8b8d8cdcf8",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "duration" : 14986283,
          "group_id" : "com",
          "var_time" : "2018-04-24T17:05:13.082-05:00",
          "var_name" : "2",
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```
public class RawDocument
{

    [PropertyName("duration")]
    public long Duration { get; set; }

    [PropertyName("group_id")]
    public string GroupId { get; set; }

    [PropertyName("var_time")]
    public DateTime Vartime { get; set; }

    [PropertyName("var_name")]
    public string Varname { get; set; }

}
```

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultMappingFor<RawDocument>(m => m
              .IndexName(test_index)
              .TypeName("doc"));

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    //argument being passed into the query is maxExtractionTime datetime values. maxExtractionTime is in UTC
    //maxExtractionTime is being compared to var_time datetime with timezone values
    DateTime maxExtractionTime;
    maxExtractionTime = DateTime oDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2019-02-08 16:10:40.000", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm.fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    var searchResponse = client.Search<RawDocument>(s => s
                .Size(5000)
                .Scroll("2m")
                .Query(q => q.DateRange(m => m.Field("var_time").GreaterThanOrEquals(maxExtractionTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")).TimeZone("+00:00")))                
                );


    while (searchResponse.Documents.Any())
        {

            foreach (var document in searchResponse.Hits)
            {
            //do some business logic on the values
            MessageBox.Show("document.Source.Duration", document.Source.Duration);
            MessageBox.Show("document.Source.Vartime", document.Source.Vartime);

            }
            searchResponse = client.Scroll<RawDocument>("2m", searchResponse.ScrollId);
        }   

    var clearScrollResponse = client.ClearScroll(c => c.ScrollId(searchResponse.ScrollId));         
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the doc you gave the link to:

> now is not affected by the time_zone parameter (dates must be stored as UTC)

From this, and the other examples on that page, one can see that the `time_zone` parameter (or `.TimeZone(...)` in C#), affects the input values to the query.  By passing `+00:00`, you're saying that the input values do not need adjusting.

The dates themselves must be stored as UTC in the document to properly perform a range query.  You shouldn't store `var_time` as `2018-04-24T17:05:13.082-05:00`, but rather as `2018-04-24T17:10:13.082Z`.  Then you can query against it.

If necessary, store two fields, so you have one to query against and one to display the original local time.

To answer your specific questions:

> 1. Am I doing it correctly in my code below?

Your query is fine, but `.TimeZone("+00:00")`is not necessary as it does nothing to adjust the arguments.  You do, however, need to ensure the timestamp in the document is stored in UTC.

> 2. Is ES going to handle the complexity of different timezone of the datetime argument before comparing it to the document datetime values ?

It is simply a convenience to adjust the arguments.  It doesn't adjust the value in the document.

> 3. Is ES going to return the documents with the original datetime timezone values ?

The document should be returned as normal.  Altering the time zone in the query doesn't affect that.

> 4. Any documentation unraveling the internals of elastic search instance timezone handling ?

I couldn't find much outside of the doc you linked to.  You should experiment to validate any assumptions.

Comment: When I saw Matt's post about timezones, I feel like "shut up and take my upvote".

Comment: @Matt: Like you rightly responded to q1, I have eliminated the unnecessary .TimeZone("+00:00") syntax. 
ES source document comes from another team and the request to change it to UTC is out of my hands.
Ref to question 2: on experimenting, the response from ES is greater than or equals to the passed datetime argument. (ES instance must assume the passed argument is in UTC). 
Educated assumption tells me that ES is comparing the document datetime with timezone values and the passed argument (datetime) with the same reference timezone (Either UTC or the document time zone). Continued..

Comment: @Matt: Followed your response to question 4: experimented and validated the results.
Caution: My assumptions might need validation from the gods who wrote the ES code. However, the validated results pass the test and my requirements. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

To add to [Matt Johnson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54719791/1831), sending a timezone is helpful when the date string input you have has one timezone offset (or the format does not specify one e.g. `2019-02-21`), but you wish Elasticsearch to convert it to another timezone offset before comparing against dates stored in the target field.

Let's look at some examples.

#### DateTimeKind.Utc

```
var client = new ElasticClient();

var maxExtractionTime = new DateTime(2019, 2, 8, 16, 10, 40, DateTimeKind.Utc);

var searchResponse = client.Search<RawDocument>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .DateRange(m => m
            .Field(f => f.Vartime)
            .GreaterThanOrEquals(maxExtractionTime)
        )
    )
);
```

serializes to

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "var_time": {
        "gte": "2019-02-08T16:10:40Z"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### DateTimeKind.Local (I'm in Australia)

```
var maxExtractionTime = new DateTime(2019, 2, 8, 16, 10, 40, DateTimeKind.Local);
```

serializes to

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "var_time": {
        "gte": "2019-02-08T16:10:40+10:00"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### DateTimeKind.Unspecified

```
var maxExtractionTime = new DateTime(2019, 2, 8, 16, 10, 40, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
```

serializes to

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "var_time": {
        "gte": "2019-02-08T16:10:40"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the first two cases, each contains a timezone offset value that Elasticsearch can use when comparing dates. With the last, no timezone offset is present, so it will be interpreted as UTC. In the latter case, you may want to send a timezone value to be used to convert the input to UTC.

There's some [history to `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset` serialization within the client](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/pull/2268). The serialization in 6.x cannot be changed, except for `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset` property types on your own POCOs, with a [custom serializer hooked up](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/custom-serialization.html). This *limitation*, if you will, is not often an issue however as most APIs within the client accept a [`DateMath` type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/date-math-expressions.html) where a formatted date string that supports date math expressions can be used. With `DateMath`, there are implicit conversions from `DateTime` and `string`, as well as methods to build more complex expressions.

Comment: Thanks for providing more clarity with the DateTimeKind use-cases. The use-cases are for the argument parameter being passed. I am assuming that this has no bearing on the timezone element of the values (datetime with timezone) in the document. Especially if the document values comes in multiple timezones. Again, thanks.

Comment: Correct - if dates have timezone offsets within the index, this will be taken into account. If none is specified for a dat, UTC will be implied.